# How to generate python code for inference from a saved Tensorflow model, but independent from Tensorflow libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to obtain python code (independent from the Tensorflow library/binaries) equivalent to my "frozen" Tensorflow trained model, to use it for inference in devices or machines that do not have Tensorflow library/binaries available.

I'm also open to using a different language, if there is no such capability with python.

Comment: Since a trained model is typically just a collection of parameters, which are used in a predefined structure there is (in theory) nothing to stop you from using those same parameters in an equivalent structure in some other library/language. Whether there is a convenient and efficient way to create that equivalent structure I think depends a lot on the device/machine you intend to use it on.

Comment: @Mandias I'm looking for an easy way to do it in python. Performing the math operations in Python should not depend on the device or machine, but it could just be a regular computer. For a short and easy network I could write it myself, but I thought there would be some tool to help. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I see, I misinterpreted your question. I don't know if there is a method to convert to just python from tensorflow, since I believe there is a lot of integration with faster C code behind the scenes. Pure python would probably be a lot slower.

Comment: @Mandias True, it will be slower. But inference is one-shot, I can afford it to take much longer than training.

Comment: Good point. If you haven't already, looking through https://github.com/danielsabinasz/TensorSlow might be a good place to start. Since it converts tensorflow itself to pure python this could make what you're trying to do easier.